# API to find if my device has cellular connectivity support

Tags: c#, uwp

I am building a UWP application. I wish to know if the device on which my app is running, supports cellular connectivity or not. Is there any way this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method:

```
public static bool TestConnectedToCellular()
{
    try
    {
        if (NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile() is ConnectionProfile connectionProfile)
        {
            return connectionProfile.IsWwanConnectionProfile;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if there is any cellular connection:
`NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles().Any(profile => profile.IsWwanConnectionProfile);`

I don't think there is a way to check for hardware support.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `NetworkHelper` class in the [Windows Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/networkhelper). It provides `ConnectionType`, `ConnectivityLevel`, `IsInternetAvailable` and other properties that may work for you, as well as events related to network connectivity changes.